# Condense long CASE statement into function for approximate string match

Tags: data-cleaning

I have a table with many seemingly duplicated company entities (tblOrganisations), for example:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Company 1 |
| 2 | Company One |
| 3 | CompanyOne |
| 4 | Company One |
| 5 | Company One (Pty)Ltd |
| 6 | Company 1(Pty) Ltd |
| 7 | Company One Pty Ltd |
| 8 | Business 1 |
| 9 | Business One |
| 10 | BusinessOne |
| 11 | Business One |
| 12 | Business One (Pty)Ltd |
| 13 | Business 1(Pty) Ltd |
| 14 | Business One Pty Ltd |

There are many more companies with many different variations in this table (~100k rows).'

I have composed an approximate string match using a case statement which cleanses these entities as per the below:

CASE WHEN tblOrganisations.Name LIKE 'Company%' THEN 'Company One (Pty) Ltd'
WHEN tblOrganisation.Name LIKE 'Business%' THEN 'Business One (Pty) Ltd' *etc*

Typically I use this case statement in my selects however it can become very cumbersome with all the different variations that I have to account for. **Note that my case statement is far more complex than this and corrects enough variation to get me to my target accuracy.

My question is:

How do I go about creating a function that I can call in my stored procedure in order to maximise the lifespan of my mousewheel?

Comment: Encapsulating your logic into a function and best approach will depend on your **RDBMS** as each vendor has varying syntax and benefits.

Comment: I am using T-SQL in SSMS.